# Axios interceptor with react redux not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, interceptor

I want to set headers in the request using Axios interceptor I have read the Axios documentation and I am doing this for that:-

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './scenes/App'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore,applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux'
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
import axios from 'axios'

import reducers from './services/store/reducers'

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk))
)

axios.interceptors.request.use(request=>{
  console.log("here")
  console.log(request)
    return request;
})

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store = {store}>
      <App/>
    </Provider>
,document.querySelector('#root'))
```

The thing is this request function is not running . Where am I going wrong ?? Do I need to do any other setup for Axios interceptor??

Comment: Where do you call to axios?

Comment: in my components

Comment: do you any console error?

Comment: i have console logged that too , but nothing is printing on console.

Comment: I got it on how to do it . Instead of making axios.intercepts.request what we can do is where we are creating our axios with base URL we can setup our interceptors using that api.